# springboot thymeleaf html create link

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf

I have this springboot thymeleaf html,

```
    @GetMapping("/rest")
    public String list(Model theModel) {

        // add to the spring model
        theModel.addAttribute("list", theModel);

        return "menu-list";
    }
```

menu-list.html,

```
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="List : ${list}">
            
                <td th:text="${list.name}" />   
                <td th:text="${list.position}" />   
                <td th:text="${list.homepage}" />
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I need to put link on the,
td th:text="${list.homepage}". Like href=www.mydomain.com.

I have no idea what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try to use the following code:

```
<td><a th:href="@{${list.homepage}}" th:text="homepage"/></td>
```